# get contents of all azure blobs via python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to list all the blobs in a container and then ultimately store each blobs contents (each blob stores a csv file) into a data frame, it appears that the blob service client is the easiest way to list all the blobs, and this is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from pathlib import Path
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def main():
    connect_str = os.environ['AZURE_CONNECT_STR']
    container   = os.environ['CONTAINER']

    print(connect_str + "\n")
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blob_list:
        print("\t" + blob.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, in the last version of blob storage client there appears to be no method which allows me to get the actual contents of the blob, what code should I be using ? there are other clients in the Python SDK for Azure, but it getting a full list of the blobs in a container using these seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would need to do is create an instance of [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) using the `container_client` and the blob's name. You can then call [`download_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download-blob) method to download the blob.

Something like:

```
for blob in blob_list:
  print("\t" + blob.name)
  blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
  blob_client.download(...)
```